# imaplib.IMAP4.error set a failure message when connecting (Python)

Tags: printing, gmail, imap, imaplib

I'm having trouble defining a message in the Gmail login code when the credentials are wrong.

```py
def connect():
    imap_host = 'imap.gmail.com'
    email = 'cryp@gmail.com'
    password = input("Password: ")
    M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host)
    M.login(email, password)
    try: 
     os.system('cls')
     print('Connected.')
    except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
     os.system('cls')
     print('Failed to connect.')
connect()
```

Below is the message that appears.

```
raise self.error(dat[-1])
imaplib.error: b'[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)'
```

and not this:

```
print('Falha ao Conectar.')
```

The message `Connected` appears correctly when I type the email and password correctly, however when I make an error this message appears instead of `Failed to connect`.

Comment: The call to .login() isn't inside the try, so why would the except catch .login() problems?

Comment: I managed to solve it, thanks friend.